# How many ids can I write at the iPhone app store ID field?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, app-store

Can i set more than one iPhone app store ID?

I have created two mobile IOS application that i want to link them to one FB app. 
That means two iPhone app store ID.
How can i do that. Is it possible?

Comment: in one application you can set only one id.

Answer (score 1):

No, every AppID defines just one App, there's no possibility or sense in doing it with more.

Answer (score 0):

you can share the same facebook app id across applications (ios applications), the facebook developers web site explains how to do that: [share-appid-across-multiple-apps-ios-sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-appid-across-multiple-apps-ios-sdk/)